# How to generate all possible arrangements of numbers from a list in Python?

Tags: python, permutation

Problem: Given a list of 3 numbers `[4, 8, 15]` generate a list of all possible arrangements of the numbers.

That's `3*3*3 = 27` unique entries from what I can gather. Something like:

```
4,4,4
4,4,8
4,4,15
4,8,4
4,8,8
4,8,15
4,15,4
4,15,8
4,15,15
...
```

I tried using `itertools.permutations` and `itertools.combinations` but I can't get all 27 values.

`list(itertools.permutations([4,8,15],3))` for example only prints 6 values:

`[(4, 8, 15), (4, 15, 8), (8, 4, 15), (8, 15, 4), (15, 4, 8), (15, 8, 4)]`

Is there something that's available  out of the box or is this more of a "roll your own" problem?

Comment: `I tried ...`. So can you share the code [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52194927/edit) so we can more accurately address your issue?

Comment: `list(itertools.product([4, 8, 15], repeat=3))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are confusing `permutations` with `product`:

```
len(list(itertools.permutations([4,8,15],3)))
# return 6
len(list(itertools.product([4,8,15], repeat=3)))
# return 27
```

Comment: Ahhh...that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is still in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). The function called `product` does the trick; it takes two arguments: first is the iterable which has the usable elements, second is the amount of times the iterable can repeat itself.

`itertools.product([4,8,15],repeat=3)` would return the permutations you want in your example.

The reason `permutations` or `combinations` don't work for you is because they don't allow items to repeat themselves; `product` calculates the cartesian product, which allows for repetition of items.

Comment: It won't work:) Notice `product`'s signature: `itertools.product(*iterables, repeat=1)`, your `3` will be considered as `iterables`.

Comment: Thanks, it's been a while since I dabbled in python.

Answer (score -1):

This code prints what you requested :)

```
list = [4,8,15]

for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range (len(list)):
        for k in range (len(list)):
            print ("("+str(list[i]) +","+str(list[j])+","+str(list[k])+")\n")
```